# Is possible return a static page in https virtual host using lighttpd?

Tags: https, redirect, lighttpd, static-content, static-files

It seems like redirect is not done.

If I put URL `https://test2/static_page` in browser it works but if I put `https://test1` don't redirect

```
SERVER["socket"] == ":443" {

  $HTTP["host"] == "test1" {
    url.redirect = ("" => "https://test2/static_page"),
    url.redirect-code = 302
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you test the config?
`lighttpd -f /etc/lighttpd/lighttpd.conf -tt`

Did you load [mod_redirect](https://wiki.lighttpd.net/mod_redirect) in the config?
`lighttpd -f /etc/lighttpd/lighttpd.conf -p`

In lighttpd.conf: `server.modules += ("mod_redirect")`